How to start Marionette with a user-specified port?
I use the following command to start marionette. In myprofile, I copied an existing profile folder and appended user_pref("marionette.port", <myport>); to prefs.js. But firefox ignores this setup and still pick a random port. How can I set a specific port for marionette to use?
MOZ_CRASHREPORTER=1 MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_NO_REPORT=1 MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_SHUTDOWN=1 MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1 $exec_opt /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --marionette -profile myprofile -foreground -no-remote

